# como crear un JSONArray a partir de multiples arrays en angular

Tags: javascript, typescript

tengo la necesidad de crar un ObjectArray a partir de tres arrays:
El primero es el principal, que contiene todas la categorías..

```
 [
        {
            "grupo": "VIDEO"
        },
        {
            "grupo": "LINEA BLANCA"
        },
        {
            "grupo": "JARDIN"
        },
       
    ]
```

El segundo el segundo describe cada uno de los tipos y enlaza las categorías con los productos.

```
[
    {
        "tipo": "MONITORES",
        "grupo": "VIDEO",
        "descrip": "MONITOR LCD. Tensión de entrada 220VAC (N FASES) + -10%, frecuencia 60Hz + - 5%, factor de eficiencia > 97%; tensión de salida 120VCA +10% -13%\n"
    },
    {
        "tipo": "MONITORES",
        "grupo": "VIDEO",
        "descrip": "PANTALLA DE 80 PLASMA Tensión de entrada 120 VAC+ -10%; frecuencia 60Hz + - 5%, factor de eficiencia >97%; tensión de salida 220VCA (N FASES)+ 10%-13% "
    },
    {
        "tipo": "ESTUFAS",
        "grupo": "LINEA BLANCA",
        "descrip": "ESTUFA DE GAS "
    },
    {
        "tipo": "LAVADORAS",
        "grupo": "LINEA BLANCA",
        "descrip": "LAVADORA Y SECADORA."
    },
    {
        "tipo": "PASTO SINTETICO",
        "grupo": "JARDIN",
        "descrip": "PASTO SINTETICO ULTRA REFORZADO"
    }
```

y el tercero es el catálogo general.....

```
[
{
    "clave": "ONILED-2018",
    "tipo": "MONITORES",
    "capacidad": "18 PULGADAS",
    "descrip": "Monitor para centros de control ",
    "precio": 380,
    "c_proved": "2018",
    "costo": null,
    "status": true
},
{
    "clave": "MAXX_green",
    "tipo": "PASTO SINTETICO",
    "capacidad": "200 kg x m2",
    "descrip": "Pasto sintético para uso rudo",
    "precio": 440,
    "c_proved": null,
    "costo": null,
    "status": true
}
]
```

y necesito crear un JSON array con este formato......

```
     catalogo = [
                {
                    categoria: 'VIDEO',
                    
                    subCategoria: [
                        {
                           tipo: 'MONITORES',
                           modelos: [
                                { CLAVE: 'ONILED-2018', PRECIO: 540 },
                                { CLAVE: 'lg_7034',  PRECIO: 740 }
                             
                            ]
                        },
     {
                           tipo: 'ACCESORIOS',
                           modelos: [
                                { CLAVE: 'CLB_HDMI', PRECIO: 15 },
                                { CLAVE: 'CNC_BNC',  PRECIO: 3 }
                             
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    categoria: 'LINEA BLANCA',
                  
                    subCategoria: [
                        {
                            tipo: 'ESTUFAS',
                            cities: [
                                { CLAVE: 'mabe4582', PRECIO: '895' },
                                { CLAVE: 'lg3212', PRECIO: '950' }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
],
```

Mi pregunta es como construir este ARRAY programáticamente en angular.
existirá alguna función que simplifique esto? ahora lo estoy haciendo a mano creando un `string` y al final lo paso  por  `JSON.parse(miCadena)`
Gracias de antemano por su ayuda
he tratado de usar un `ForEach` para el primer array pero no me ha funcionado

Answer (score 0):

Te responderé en términos de javascript, ya que en Angular aplica transparentemente.

Tu problema se traduce en varias agrupaciones que debes realizar para tener el resultado esperado, para ello puedes valerte de 3 funciones:

- [Object.groupBy()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/groupBy) : Esta es una nueva funcionalidad que tiene javascript para la agrupación
- [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries): `groupBy` retorna un objeto a modo de diccionario. Puedes valerte de la función `entries` para recorrer el par `[clave,valor]` de este diccionario
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map): Esta función recorre un array, donde en cada iteración puedes transformar el item en un nuevo item

Ejemplo:

```js
const array1= [
    {
        "tipo": "MONITORES",
        "grupo": "VIDEO",
        "descrip": "MONITOR LCD. Tensión de entrada 220VAC (N FASES) + -10%, frecuencia 60Hz + - 5%, factor de eficiencia > 97%; tensión de salida 120VCA +10% -13%\n"
    },
    {
        "tipo": "MONITORES",
        "grupo": "VIDEO",
        "descrip": "PANTALLA DE 80 PLASMA Tensión de entrada 120 VAC+ -10%; frecuencia 60Hz + - 5%, factor de eficiencia >97%; tensión de salida 220VCA (N FASES)+ 10%-13% "
    },
    {
        "tipo": "ESTUFAS",
        "grupo": "LINEA BLANCA",
        "descrip": "ESTUFA DE GAS "
    },
    {
        "tipo": "LAVADORAS",
        "grupo": "LINEA BLANCA",
        "descrip": "LAVADORA Y SECADORA."
    },
    {
        "tipo": "PASTO SINTETICO",
        "grupo": "JARDIN",
        "descrip": "PASTO SINTETICO ULTRA REFORZADO"
    }
]

const array2= [
{
    "clave": "ONILED-2018",
    "tipo": "MONITORES",
    "capacidad": "18 PULGADAS",
    "descrip": "Monitor para centros de control ",
    "precio": 380,
    "c_proved": "2018",
    "costo": null,
    "status": true
},
{
    "clave": "MAXX_green",
    "tipo": "PASTO SINTETICO",
    "capacidad": "200 kg x m2",
    "descrip": "Pasto sintético para uso rudo",
    "precio": 440,
    "c_proved": null,
    "costo": null,
    "status": true
}
];

function groupBy(arr,exp) {
    return arr.reduce((acc, i) => {
        acc[exp(i)] ? acc[exp(i)].push(i) : acc[exp(i)] = [i];
        return acc;
    }, {});
}

//agrupamos por categorias
const categorias = groupBy(array2, item => array1.find(a=>a.tipo == item.tipo).grupo);

//recorremos cada categoria y modificamos el contenido
const result =  Object.entries(categorias).map(([key, value])=>{
   
  //agrupamos por subcategoria
  let subCategoria = groupBy(value, ({tipo})=> tipo );
  
  //recorremos cada subcategoria y modificamos el contenido
  subCategoria = Object.entries(subCategoria).map( ([k,v]) => ({ 
      tipo:k,
      modelos: v.map(a=> ({ CLAVE : a.clave, PRECIO : a.precio})) //solo tomamos la clave y el precio
    })
  );
  
  //retornanos un objeto como resultado
  return {
      categoria: key,
      subCategoria: subCategoria
   };

});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: la ejecutarlo, le envía el siguiete error ( en Angular 16):

Comment: La propiedad 'groupBy' no existe en el tipo 'ObjectConstructor'

Comment: @hugofernandez Seguramente tu navegador no está actualizado o usas un navegador de segunda categoría como safari o firefox. En mi respuesta está el link a la documentación oficial de la función `groupBy` ahí puedes ver la compatibilidad y al final de la página hay un enlace para un polyfill

Comment: el error no lo manda el navegador, lo manda Angular y estoy usando la versión 16

Comment: @hugofernandez En ese caso creas la función, algo así como el código que he dejado en la respuesta